# Folding at Home in LUBUNTU 15.04 with an R9 270

Tags: ati, lubuntu, 15.04, fglrx

I haven't used linux in quite a while. I used to fold in Ubuntu around 9.04, before they even had a GUI of anykind. In anycase this is what I've done already.

1. ran `sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates`

This will install AMD Drivers for my R9 270 video card

2. Downloaded and installed the `Fahclient.deb`
3. Downloaded and installed the `Fahcontrol.deb`

For steps 2 and 3 I just double clicked the deb file and opened them with gib installer (followed the menu's for easy installation)

These files will install the core folding at home client and the control in which settings can be modified.

4. Run Folding at Home (Start -> Education -> Fah)

I ran this for a few hours to see what the PPD was like. I've read that it should be 60-80k, in Windows 7 I was getting at least 25-35k. It was currently getting no higher than 1700 PPD with a core 17 project.

I'd normally open AMD Catalyst and go to the Overdrive tab to see the details of what speeds my GPU is currently operating with. The interface in Ubuntu doesn't seem to have the Overdrive part, so I downloaded the AMD Catalyst Ctrl (seperate and open source).

Using this new application I was able to set the minimum and maximum speeds to 1050 (its gone as high as 1100, but there are no options for that). The performance seem to rise but only to about 7k PPD.

My question is did I miss something? My only thought now is maybe the QuickReturnBonus only kicks in after 10 projects so the PPD looks terrible now, but even without the QRB, can it really be this low?